# Why do <a href=#A> and jquery click function not work together?

Tags: jquery, html, href

What I want is that: There is a link on top of page. When it is clicked, it should go to   in the same page and toggle a div class with jquery.But both of are not working at the same time.. For example:

```
<a href='#A' id='link'>Go to A and toggle a div class</a>
```

jquery codes are:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').toggle();
   });

   <a name='A'> Here is A </a>
```

my codes are more complex than that but same logic with I write here. When I click the link, the div which has toggle class toggles. First it looks jquery codes. But it does not go to #A. That is to say, href attribute is not working. Any idea?...

Comment: how about a small sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example please.

Comment: This should work just fine.  Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/v8Z53/.

Comment: In example you showed,there is div id=A, but i did with a name=A..

Comment: Is it possible you have `event.preventDefault()` somewhere else in your JS that affects anchor tags?

Comment: May be there is problem with your HTML part. Please show your HTML as well.

Comment: My browser firefox.... My codes are with php and it is  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664312/how-to-link-to-a-specific-part-in-the-same-page-with-jquery-and-php

Answer (score 3):

click() will not fire the default event so you have to [set window.location](http://unitstep.net/blog/2010/04/12/triggering-links-from-javascript-using-jquery/)

```
$('#link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.toggle').toggle();
    window.location.hash = ($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"));
});
```